# Create a coordinate pair from this code

Tags: python, list, split, coordinates

Here is my current code

```
a_reader = None
a_reader     = open('data.csv', 'rU')
a_csv_reader = csv.reader(a_reader)

for row in a_csv_reader:
       print row
a_reader.close()

count = 0
sum   = 0.0
a_reader     = open('data.csv', 'rU')
a_csv_reader = csv.reader(a_reader)
a_csv_reader.next()

for row in a_csv_reader:
        if count != 0 and row[0] != '':
            sum = sum + float(row[0])
        count = count + 1

a_reader.close()
print 'Number of lines is:',count
print 'Sum is:',sum
return listStation
```

This produces the results below

```
['1', '476050', '7709929']    
['2', '473971', '7707713']    
['3', '465676', '7691097']    
['4', '515612', '7702192']    
['5', '516655', '7704405']    
['6', '519788', '7713255']    
['7', '538466', '7683341']    
Number of lines is: 8    
Sum is: 28.0
```

Ok so the output that I want is shown below in a double list.

```
[[476050, 7709929],[473971, 7707713],[465676, 7691097],[515612, 7702192],[516655, 7704405],[519788, 7713255],[538466, 7683341]]
```

How can I alter my code to produce the result as a double list as shown above. Is it possible to create a doublelist of coordinate pairs as shown above. Can you help me?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Slice off the last two elements, then append.

```
>>> ['1', '476050', '7709929'][1:3]
['476050', '7709929']
```

Comment: @Haidro This appears to be the problem. How can I slice the last two lines off first using my code.

Comment: @KristoferWright Instead of `for row in a_csv_reader: print row` Just do `[row[-2:] for row in a_csv_reader]`

Comment: @Haidro can you edit my code I have tried that but it keeps saying syntax error :/

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes but where does this get implemented in my code as what you have shown is from printing csv reader

Comment: @KristoferWright I have added an answer. I'm not 100% what you mean

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = []
    total = 0
    for row in itertools.islice(reader, 1, None): # Skip a header
        if row[0]:
            total += int(row[0])
            rows.append(row[1:])

print 'Number of lines is:', len(rows)
print 'total is', total
print rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
for row in a_csv_reader:
    print row
```

Use a list comprehension to slice the list:

```
for i in [row[-2:] for row in a_csv_reader]:
    print i
```

Which prints:

```
['476050', '7709929']
['473971', '7707713']
['465676', '7691097']
['515612', '7702192']
['516655', '7704405']
['519788', '7713255']
['538466', '7683341']
```

So thus `[row[-2:] for row in a_csv_reader]` is:

```
[['476050', '7709929'], ['473971', '7707713'], ['465676', '7691097'], ['515612', '7702192'], ['516655', '7704405'], ['519788', '7713255'], ['538466', '7683341']]
```

Which is your expected output.

Comment: Thanks @Haidro this is perfect I can now fiddle with this from here to apply further values and functions. Thanks